# Different between '-s' and '-vf scale=' in ffmpeg, especially in two-pass transcoding?

Tags: ffmpeg

Different between '-s' and '-vf scale=' in ffmpeg?

And for a two-pass transcoding in ffmpeg, what's the difference or influence then?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## There should be no difference in the output

Using the [md5 muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#md5-1) to compare.

#### `-s`

```
$ ffmpeg -i input -an -s 640x360 -f md5 -
...
MD5=6280d86947e18d6633f4eddc299cf8a4
```

#### `-vf scale`

```
$ ffmpeg -i input -an -vf scale=640:360 -f md5 -
...
MD5=6280d86947e18d6633f4eddc299cf8a4
```

I believe `-s` is mapped to `scale` but I'm not totally sure and did not look at the source code to find out.

---

## There are advantages to using `scale` instead of `-s`

- You can use it with other filters and determine exactly where in the filtergraph you want the scale to occur.
- It is more flexible because you can use additional options and expressions.
- You can just declare one dimension and `scale` can automatically determine the other while preserving aspect ratio: `scale=640:-1`.

See the [FFmpeg scale video filter documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) for more info.